# Difference between bitmap.save overloads

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I was looking at the different ways I can save a bitmap object to a Memory Stream and I am not sure which method I should choose.

The two in particular that intrigue me are :

1)

```
Bitmap.Save(Stream, ImageFormat)
```

2)

```
Bitmap.Save(Stream, ImageCodecInfo, EncoderParameters)
```

The scenario is as follows:

I have a method that takes in an image in the format .bmp and after I performed my resize logic I save this new resized bitmap object back to a memory stream in jpg format. I have used both methods and they are both giving me the encoded jpg equivalent.

Logic for method 1)

```
Bitmap srcBitmap = new Bitmap(m_testImage);
//perform resize
var imageStream = new MemoryStream();
srcBitmap.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
imageStream.Position = 0L;
```

Logic for method 2)

```
Bitmap srcBitmap = new Bitmap(m_testImage);
myjpegEncoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 80L);
var imageStream = new MemoryStream();
srcBitmap.Save(imageStream, myjpegEncoder, encoderParams);
imageStream.Position = 0L;
```

What are the main differences between these two approaches?

msdn: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.save(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.save%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change Quality, ColorDepth, or Compression etc. when save with method 2.

Comment: @Matthew: They are pretty much *exactly* the same. All your first (two parameter) overload does is get `ImageCodecInfo` for you by calling `ImageFormat.FindEncoder`. Then it actually uses that to call the second overload (three parameters), passing `null` for the `EncoderParameters` parameter.

Comment: Just to clarify what may not be obvious: On the .NET side, the only (very slight) performance difference when passing parameters will be that those parameters have to be marshaled to pass them to GDI+. On the GDI+ side, the encoder may be faster (or slower) at default parameters than the ones you happen to specify. For example, some reports (haven't checked) say that saving a JPEG with default parameters and no changes will make the encoder simply save the original image without re-encoding it - which will obviously be faster than re-encoding it.

Answer (score -1):

the first is a predefined method for JPEG.
The other is a more generic version. e.g. for future image formats which are not yet directly available like in the first sample

Comment: In the case of the second form, you can probably specify parameters that let you control how much compression is applied to the image

Comment: Yes, but that is kinda obvious when looking at the code

Comment: again a downvote.
guys... before downvoting think about it. Why do you have to specify a GUID for the encoder? Exactly because of future image formats not implemented in .net yet. 
When examining the decompiled code, it reveals that it works exactly this way. See GdipGetImageEncoders()